# jQuery initiated CSS transition glitching out when triggered repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I am trying to fade an element in and out quickly on a button press. Here's the jQuery and CSS code:

```js
$('#button').on("click", function () {
    $('.alert_itemadded').show(0, function() {
        $('.alert_itemadded').toggleClass('alert_itemadded_fade');
        $('.alert_itemadded').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.alert_itemadded').toggleClass('alert_itemadded_fade');
                $('.alert_itemadded').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
                    $('.alert_itemadded').hide();
                });
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.alert_itemadded {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.alert_itemadded_fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

The code works fine, except for if you click the button before the fadein/out transition sequence completes. If you click during the transition, the "alert_itemadded" element will still fadein correctly, but then immediately hide without properly fading out. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Things I've tried that haven't been successful:

- Using addClass & removeClass instead of toggleClass.
- Adding $('.alert_itemadded').finish() right after the button click event to terminate the currently running transition.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unfortunately still not able to figure out how to get the effect I wanted (where the previous transition stops cleanly, and the new transition starts up again like normal). I ended up simply adding a T/F variable which indicated whether a transition was in progress. If it was, I ignored the normal button click code.

Hope this workaround helps someone else. If I end up figuring out how to do this transition restart the right way, I will post that solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button and enable it again after the transition ends. Something like this:

```
$('#button').on("click", function () {
    var button =  $(this);
    button .attr('disabled', 'true');
    $('.alert_itemadded').show(0, function() {
        $('.alert_itemadded').toggleClass('alert_itemadded_fade');
        $('.alert_itemadded').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.alert_itemadded').toggleClass('alert_itemadded_fade');
                $('.alert_itemadded').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
                    $('.alert_itemadded').hide();
                });
                button .attr('disabled', 'false');
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What I've presented above is a bit of a simplification of the actual scenario. I need the transition sequence to restart every time the button is clicked, whether there is a transition already running or not.